# Change in "li" with two classes

Tags: html, css

I have

```
<li class="item itemshad edited">
  <div class="itemsetting" style="">
    <span class="icon"><i class="icon-home"></i></span>
    <span class="inputspan" style="float: left;margin-top: 1px;"><input class="menuName" type="text" value="Text" style=""></span><span class="list" style="margin-left: 6px;"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></span>
  </div>
</li>

<li class="item itemshad edited selected">
  <div class="itemsetting" style="">
    <span class="icon"><i class="icon-home"></i></span>
    <span class="inputspan" style="float: left;margin-top: 1px;"><input class="menuName" type="text" value="Text" style=""></span><span class="list" style="margin-left: 6px;"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></span>
  </div>
</li>
```

if the "li" has a class of the selected and edited to change the thickness of the border in input.

if that's so

```
.selected .edited input  {
    border: 2px dotted #ccc;
}
```

Does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To specify multiple classes on a single element, just join them together:

```
.selected.edited input
```

This is because the space character is a combinator that means "any descendant of"

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
.selected.edited input
```

Removed the space character. Otherwise `.edited` has to be inside `.selected`.

Comment: Please check your answer, I edited it (to style the code and and amend `spacebar` to `space character`).

Answer (score 1):

It Should be

```
.edited.selected input  {
    border: 2px dotted #ccc;
}
```

For more info on Multiple Class / ID and Class Selectors - http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/